# Android Play Store hijacking focus after in-app purchase dialog

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

anyone know what could be done about this?

basically if the Play Store app is still running in the background - which is going to be the case for most users once they first download and install the app - after interaction with any in-app purchase-related dialog box the Play Store is brought back into focus and users must make there way back to the app to complete tasks. how can this be prevented?

Comment: this is terrible. didnt start happening until the app was published and went live.

Comment: reported this as a bug:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=32878

Comment: it has been noticed that a similar app does not launch Google Play as a separate task at the point of sale, but ours does. could this be a factor and/or is Google Play being launched an undesired action, result of a coding error?

Comment: buy "task" i mean "process" - apologies

Comment: Have bumped this as a good question as I am also having the same issue. Out of interest are you using a standard market code approach or on you wrote yourself?